# Android: How to keep Animation after Animation

Tags: android, animation

I'm implementing `animation` when slide between `fragments` in `ViewPager`.
when slide to new `fragment` I want to `scale` the `view` and the make start a `set of animation` includes `alpha` and `translate` `animation` but when start the `set` problem is `scale animation`'s result was not keeping (the view return to the original size).
I had tried to with

```
scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
```

But it just work when I do not start set of `animation` above, When I start the `set`, the `view` is return to original size.

Any body can give me a solution?

**EDIT:**

First thing I want to scale an `imageView` by `animation`:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1.3f, 1f, 1.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    scaleAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
```

Then I want after scale, `ImageView` still keep new scale size and start another `Animation` as:

```
private void startSetAnimation() {
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    set.setDuration(3000);
    set.setFillAfter(true);
    float alphaS = 1f;
    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(currentAlpha, alphaS);
    alpha.setDuration(3000);
    alpha.setFillAfter(true);
    float scale =  0.1f;
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, currentTrans,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, scale,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF , 0f);
    translate.setFillAfter(true);
    translate.setDuration(3000);
    set.addAnimation(translate);
    set.addAnimation(alpha);
    ivHorizontal.startAnimation(set);
}
```

So I add below code to `scale animation` to make it but not success.

```
scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startSetAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    ivHorizontal.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an onAnimationEnd listener you can utilize kick off certain animations when other ones are done. I'll post code when I get to my computer

### Edit:

The reason why your imageView doesn't retain its new size after scaling is because Animations aren't permanent, what you need to do is this

```
 scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // change the actual width and height so it doesn't go back to what it was

        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParmas) ivHorizontal.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = ivHorizental.getWidth();
        layoutParams.height= ivHorizental.getHeight();
        ivHorizontal.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        ivHorizontal.requestLayout();
        startSetAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
ivHorizontal.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: I had tried with AnimationListener but still not working :(

Comment: I tried to Start set when scale animation end --> not working (same result)

Comment: Do you mean the view gets back to its original size? can you post code or images. I am having problems understanding what you mean

Comment: Thank you @Antwan Kakki , I added my code. Could you plz have a look?

Comment: I can not call the method setWidth and setHeight :(

Comment: Sorry I had a derp moment, try now

Comment: I got below problem : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Also I tried to change to RelativeLayout but it's not success :(

Comment: according to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html , every view has its own layout params, try to get the ImageView ones, try the new edited code

Comment: thank you for your help but I still do not resolve my problem with your suggestion :(

Comment: no problem, sorry it didnt work :(, I need to sleep as it is 1 AM here, I'll try to find time and make a project and come back with something that works for sure tomorrow